# problem uunderstanding chain rule proof step

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to understand the proof of the chain rule explained in this page:

http://math.ucsd.edu/~wgarner/math20a/chainrule.htm

I don't understand why f (x+h) = f (x) + u (x, h).

I really don't get what u is and it dont allows me to uderstand the rest.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a definition.  The function $u(x,h)$ is defined, for all values of $x$ and $h$, to be $g(x+h)-g(x)$.

What you've linked is not quite a proof, however.  It is an outline of a proof, but it doesn't make it clear why we can be rigorous in writing substitutions like $u(x,h)\approx h g'(x)$.

Comment: oh so basically u (x, h) is a function wich definition is g (x+h)-g (x)?

Comment: @kprincipe Think of it as an error function.  $g(x+h)$ is an approximation to $g(x)$ when $h$ is close to $0$, and $u(x,h)$ measures exactly how close.  The key to understanding the chain rule is that $u(x,h)$ is very nearly a linear function.